# Apache server phpinfo() displaying over all php pages

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos

I've set up a centOS server with apache, php and mysql installed. I've uploaded my db and php pages, but whenever I view the php files from a browser I get the phpinfo() page displaying, followed by the php page below. Any suggestions??

Comment: Check your php.ini for `auto_prepend_file` configuration option .. or the same via .htaccess/Apache config file if it is allowing to setting up php config variable in such way.

Comment: The auto_prepend_file config is blank

Answer (score 1):

You can run `grep -lr phpinfo /var/www/` to find the file. I think it is in one include file that is included()/required() in all pages.

Comment: After running that command is displays: /var/www/html/myphpfile.php /var/www/html/myphpfile.php~ Any idea why one of my files is being shown as phpinfo?

Comment: @Ben: No, but if you grep again through `/var/www` and your Apache config for that filename I'll bet you'll find an indication.